# How to add a button to a API v2 Google Maps marker

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am working on an android Google Maps app, and am having trouble with map markers.

This question might have a trivial solution but after searching, I have only found links on how to add a marker with a button. What I want is different: I want a marker whose respective dialog box has a button.

Has anyone done anything similar to this?

Comment: There is no "dialog box" associated with markers in Maps V2. Do you mean the info window that appears when you tap on a marker?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Sorry for that, but yes exactly that info window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can create an `InfoWindowAdapter`, and attach it to your `GoogleMap` via `setInfoWindowAdapter()`, to tailor the contents of an info window to contain a `Button`, the `Button` will not be clickable. The `View`  you return from `getInfoContents()` in `InfoWindowAdapter` is not displayed. Rather, it is converted into a `Bitmap`, and that image is what is displayed.

However, you can find out when the user taps on the info window via an `OnInfoWindowClickListener` registered via `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` on your `GoogleMap`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not find good help since I was using dialog instead of info window before. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

The remarks from @CommonsWare about the `InfoContent` getting converted to a `Bitmap` are true. Therefor you cannot use the InfoWindows. Try to use the `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` event instead to display your own view on top of the MapView. The `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` will help you to use clicked marker  as a parameter.

If you want to display the view on the correct position, you have to calculate the screen-position. Use the Projection's `toScreenLocation(LatLng location)` method returning `Point`   to convert the LatLng to the screen position w.r.t GoogleMap.

See [Projection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection) for more information.